# Ubuntu installation on external hard disk drive

Tags: installation, partitioning, hard-drive

My internal harddisk in my laptop got corrupted so I have removed. I loaded desktop ubuntu for testing from pendrive. Now i want to install to my external hard disk. It already has 650gb of data in ntfs format.

Remaining space i splitted to ext4 and installed. When restarting, am not getting ubuntu loaded from HDD.

Please explain how to make my ubuntu load from external hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

Move the external drive to the top in the boot order. [Here's](http://www.howtogeek.com/129815/beginner-geek-how-to-change-the-boot-order-in-your-computers-bios/) a guide for modifying the boot order and applying it.